# AS3 - Referencing a MC nested inside another MC - there has to be an easy way?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, nested, movieclip

The problem is simple.  I have a "levels" frame that contains 1 MovieClip instance named "levelbuttons".  Inside this MC are all of the level buttons instance named p1l1Btn, p1l2Btn, etc. (so I can reference all 45 buttons at once).  However, I'm having trouble referencing each individual button - specifically to gotoAndStop to a different frame of the button.

From what I have read I should be able to reference the buttons with a line like `levelbuttons.p1l1Btn.gotoAndStop(2);` - however, this generates Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Suggestions or ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: It seems like this would be a very common need (calling one MovieClip that is nested within another)?  I've googled for a couple of hours and am empty handed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that shows storing references to buttons in an array (store everything in arrays).

```
var aButtons: Array = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < aButtons.length; i++) {
    var mcNewButton: MyButton = new MyButton();
    mcButtons.addChild(mcNewButton);
    mcNewButton.x = i * 100;
    mcNewButton.iButtonID = i;
    mcNewButton.tMaintText.text = "Button " + i;
    mcNewButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fButtonPress);
    aButtons.push(mcNewButton);
}
```

Then you can reference the buttons like this: aButtons[i]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'd really like to stick with the method I'm using as it solves some other problems I have and makes things easier overall (for me).

Answer (score 0):

levelbuttons.p1l1Btn.gotoAndStop(2); works after all...

Just have to call it after the buttons have been added to stage :facepalm: